# Time complexity of my solution to Word Puzzle? Better Solution?

Tags: c#, algorithm, time-complexity

```
char[][] puzzle = new char[][] {
           // 0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16 
    new [] { 'T', 'S', 'T', 'N', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'R', 'P', 'D', 'N', 'L', 'L', 'A', 'M', 'S', 'G' },
    new [] { 'T', 'O', 'P', 'P', 'E', 'R', 'P', 'I', 'N', 'E', 'W', 'I', 'H', 'R', 'E', 'D', 'R' },
    new [] { 'O', 'T', 'E', 'V', 'I', 'T', 'S', 'E', 'F', 'C', 'O', 'G', 'R', 'E', 'R', 'N', 'E' },
    new [] { 'F', 'R', 'E', 'S', 'H', 'C', 'U', 'T', 'E', 'O', 'D', 'H', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'E' },
    new [] { 'D', 'D', 'N', 'A', 'T', 'S', 'I', 'G', 'T', 'R', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'I', 'L', 'N' },
    new [] { 'O', 'S', 'N', 'A', 'O', 'F', 'R', 'H', 'A', 'A', 'N', 'S', 'S', 'W', 'V', 'R', 'I' },
    new [] { 'E', 'S', 'N', 'N', 'M', 'A', 'G', 'A', 'R', 'T', 'I', 'F', 'I', 'C', 'I', 'A', 'L' },
    new [] { 'S', 'E', 'A', 'O', 'L', 'E', 'G', 'N', 'A', 'E', 'K', 'C', 'H', 'R', 'Y', 'G', 'S' },
    new [] { 'A', 'T', 'M', 'S', 'I', 'I', 'N', 'O', 'I', 'T', 'A', 'R', 'B', 'E', 'L', 'E', 'C' },
    new [] { 'H', 'T', 'S', 'R', 'E', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'R', 'D', 'T', 'M', 'A', 'A', 'N', 'S', 'S' },
    new [] { 'C', 'I', 'S', 'T', 'A', 'L', 'A', 'A', 'S', 'R', 'E', 'R', 'G', 'A', 'R', 'E', 'E' },
    new [] { 'R', 'N', 'E', 'P', 'O', 'F', 'D', 'R', 'E', 'T', 'L', 'C', 'C', 'I', 'H', 'R', 'L' },
    new [] { 'U', 'G', 'K', 'I', 'R', 'I', 'E', 'E', 'O', 'Y', 'R', 'Y', 'E', 'C', 'F', 'E', 'G' },
    new [] { 'P', 'U', 'I', 'N', 'T', 'U', 'L', 'E', 'E', 'C', 'D', 'I', 'N', 'M', 'S', 'T', 'L' },
    new [] { 'N', 'P', 'A', 'I', 'U', 'O', 'C', 'T', 'R', 'N', 'E', 'A', 'K', 'N', 'B', 'A', 'S' },
    new [] { 'E', 'D', 'O', 'I', 'T', 'R', 'N', 'E', 'A', 'T', 'R', 'D', 'I', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'G' },
    new [] { 'E', 'N', 'S', 'C', 'E', 'N', 'T', 'C', 'R', 'B', 'M', 'T', 'A', 'R', 'N', 'Y', 'R' } };

    String[] words = new String[] {
"ANGEL", "ARTIFICIAL", "BRANCHES", "CANDY CANES", "CELEBRATION", "DECEMBER", "DECORATE", "DECORATIONS", 
"FESTIVE", "FRESHCUT", "GARLAND", "GIFTS", "GREEN", "LARGE", "LIGHTS", "NEEDLES", "ORNAMENTS",
"PINE", "PRESENTS", "PURCHASE", "REAL", "SCENT", "SETTING UP", "SKIRT", "SMALL", "SPRUCE", "STAND", "STAR", "TAKING DOWN",
"TINSEL", "TOPPER", "TRADITION", "TREE FARM", "TREE LOT", "TRUNK", "WATER", "YEARLY", "HELLO WORLD"
};
```

A puzzle is stored in a 2d array and words are in an array. Determine how many words are in the puzzle. A word can be vertical, horizontal, or diagonal.

String can be created from char[], so one row is one string. Then I can use string.IndexOf method to find if the row contains a given word.

Hence I need to transform the puzzle to find words in all directions.

- HorizontalTransform():

```
AB => BA
CD    DC
```

- VerticalTransform():

```
    AB => AC
    CD    BD
```

- DiagonalTransform():

```
    AB => C
    CD    AD
          B
```

**[Here is the C# code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nlgtl7vsos37d9f/WordPuzzle.cs?dl=0) with test case and nice output**.

Now I compute the time complexity. Assume the size of puzzle is n*n, the count of words is m, the average length of words is a.

string.IndexOf takes O(a+n). 
string.IndexOf is called on every word and every row: O(mn(a+n)).

So the time complexity of my solution is O(mn(a+n)). Am I correct? Do you have faster solution?

Comment: If you have working code and need reviewing/feedback, consider posting this on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you're right. Cause `a` is a const, then `IndexOf` can take O(a + n) or O(a × n), but both of these estimates equivalents O(n). If you simplify big-O expression it takes O(m × n<sup>2</sup>).

It seems that it's impossible to develop a faster algorithm. Consider a simple case: we need to find all occurrences of the first letter of the word. The number of letters in the matrix increases in proportion to n<sup>2</sup>. For `m` words it takes O(m × n<sup>2</sup>) in any case.

Comment: Is my solution brute force? If not, what is a brute force solution?

Comment: As far as I understand, any solution of the problem is a brute force. You can pre-create the dictionary of first letters to accelerate the search, but since the number of first letters is O(n^2), the complexity of algorithm will still be O(m * n^2).